# Could someone provide a demonstation of Laravel using the GET method with a query string?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, get

Example: website.com/form?name=John%20Hancock&city=Atlanta

I've gone through several tutorials and forums looking for a clean demonstration of this but can't seem to come across anyone making use of it.

The Laravel 4 docs state:

> Note: Since HTML forms only support POST and GET, PUT and DELETE methods will be spoofed by automatically adding a _method hidden field to your form.

Does that imply that you're unable to use URL query strings with Laravel by default?

I have a very basic PHP script that sends usage information via GET URLs to a another PHP program running on a different server across the LAN.

Example: 192.168.1.100/useractivity.php?id=12345&loginattempts=4&ip=12.34.56.78

With that being said, should I be using another method to transmit data with Laravel? Post? Curl? Thank you.

Comment: build me a house and I will build you a tutorial

Comment: Sadly, I'm no carpenter.

Comment: Query strings will work fine though pretty urls are mostly preferred ex `/id/12345/loginattempts/4/ip/12.34.56.78`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure why you couldnt find a standard get tutorial for URLs

but everything you do is within the route.php file

so:

```
Route::get('/index/{query}', 'HomeController@index');

class HomeController extends BaseController {
  public function index($query)
    {
//do something with $query
}
```

this translate into

www.example.com/public/index/var1=1&....

(public is there only if you didnt map your Vhost properly and left public/ folder dangling.

NOTE: this is not a complete solution, the reason is that you should learn how to filter and manipulate your route data properly.

there are many ways to do this and dont forget to sanitize your get.

Comment: Thank you azngunit81. I'll put it to use.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything extra in your `route` declaration to add query string, just build your `URL`, for example something like this:

```
domain.com/users/1?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

You may declare the route something like this:

```
Route::get('users/{id}', 'UserController@index');
```

Then in the `index` use:

```
public function index($id)
{
    // $id will contain 1 from the url
    $key1 = Input::get('key1');
    $key2 = Input::get('key2');
}
```

That's it.